# What is the correct way of setting up Apache reverse proxy tomcat (Jenkins, Sonar)

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, jenkins, proxy

We are trying to setup a reverse proxy for our software factory. We could manage to put all Atlassian suite under the reverse proxy but struggled to do so with Jenkins and Sonar.

here is the apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/atoe.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/atoe.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/bundle.crt

            ProxyRequests Off
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyVia Off

            <Proxy *>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Require all granted
            </Proxy>
            <Proxy http://localhost:9010/jenkins*>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
            </Proxy>

            ProxyPass /confluence http://localhost:8090/confluence
            ProxyPassReverse /confluence http://localhost:8090/confluence

            ProxyPass /bitbucket http://localhost:7990/bitbucket
            ProxyPassReverse /bitbucket http://localhost:7990/bitbucket

            ProxyPass / http://localhost:8095/
            ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8095/

            ProxyPass /sonarqube http://localhost:9000/sonarqube
            ProxyPassReverse /sonarqube http://localhost:9000/sonarqube
</VirtualHost>
```

Both Sonarqube and Jenkins are running under Tomcat 7.0.69. I have changed their context in sonar.properties and /etc/default/jenkins, setting the right context as shown above. When trying to connect to these tools via the proxy, I got error 404.

Nothing is mentioned in the logs of apache2.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the order of ProxyPass is important. If we define a "/", it has to be defined at the end, otherwise, nothing will be considered after that.

In our case, we had:

```
        ProxyPass /confluence http://localhost:8090/confluence
        ProxyPassReverse /confluence http://localhost:8090/confluence

        ProxyPass /bitbucket http://localhost:7990/bitbucket
        ProxyPassReverse /bitbucket http://localhost:7990/bitbucket

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8095/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8095/

        ProxyPass /sonarqube http://localhost:9000/sonarqube
        ProxyPassReverse /sonarqube http://localhost:9000/sonarqube
```

to make it work, we had to invert the last two:

```
        ProxyPass /confluence http://localhost:8090/confluence
        ProxyPassReverse /confluence http://localhost:8090/confluence

        ProxyPass /bitbucket http://localhost:7990/bitbucket
        ProxyPassReverse /bitbucket http://localhost:7990/bitbucket

        ProxyPass /sonarqube http://localhost:9000/sonarqube
        ProxyPassReverse /sonarqube http://localhost:9000/sonarqube

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8095/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8095/
```